# How to target the text in an element but not the text in nested elements with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a strong tag inside a div and inside the div (before the strong element) I have text:

```
<div class="div1">
    "Text"
    <strong>
        "Text 2"
    </strong>
</div>
```

I want to apply a style to .div1, but not the strong element.

Comment: What do you mean by select? Apply style?

Comment: @pseudoAJ Yes, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text nodes cannot be selected nor styled using CSS. If you want to select the text only, you will need to use another element (adding an extra node that can be styled) like this:

```
<div class="div1">
    <span>"Text"<span>
    <strong>
        "Text 2"
    </strong>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div1 span {
    /* Your rules */
}
```

Added from my comment:

You could also consider applying a style to the `div`, then applying a style to the `strong` that reverses that style. As an example situation, your document's default text color is black, and you want to make the text in the `div` red with the exception of the `strong` element. So you apply a red text color to the `div`, and a black text color (which basically reverses the red color) to the `strong` element.

Comment: Hum... I'm working in a Stylish theme, so I can't change the HTML or something. I've just using different classes but the HTML still the same.

Comment: @Nirewen Have you considered applying a style to the `div` and then applying a style to the `strong` that reverses that style? Like for example your document's default text color is black, and you want to make the text in the div red with the exception of the strong element. So you apply a red text color to the `div`, and a black text color (which basically reverses the red color) to the `strong`.

Comment: That's what I did! Thank you =)

Comment: @Nirewen Great to hear! I've just added the content from my comment into my answer, to make it a more complete answer to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself

```
.div1 {
    visibility: collapse;
    font-size: 0px;
}

.div1 strong {
    visibility: visible;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Thank everybody for the help =)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two CSS rules like this:

```
.div1 {
  color: red;
}
.div1 strong {
  color: initial;
}
```

The first one sets a property for the whole div, the second one resets it for the `strong` tag.

Here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LZYZPp